# creating a generic function to copy different objects

Tags: java, object, java-8, copy

so i have a use case where i need to *copy* an `object` of `class`es ( classes may vary depending on the input type in factory.

here is a sample of what i am trying to do

```
public interface DataUtil {

    // the main wrapper 
    static Object copyObject(Object payload){
        if(payload instanceof Human))
            return copyEntry((Human) payload);
        if(payload instanceof Car))
            return copyEntry((Car) payload);
        if(payload instanceof Planet))
            return copyEntry((Planet) payload);        
        return payload;
    }

    static Human copyEntry(Human human) {
        return Human.builder()
                .name(human.getName())
                .age(human.getAge())
                .build();
    }

    static Car copyEntry(Car car) {
        return Car.builder()
                .model(car.getModel())
                .brand(car.getBrand())
                .build();
    }

    static Planet copyEntry(Planet planet) {
        // return builder like previous
    }
}
```

If you look at `copyObject` function, it does the job as intended but he issue is in return type. At present, to make itself *compatible*, its returning an `Object` but i would rather prefer to return it specific class Object ( say `Human` or `Car` for instance )

Is there a way to get this done with Generics (using `<T>`)? or is this a bad approach in the first place to do?

Comment: How about copy constructors?

Comment: @MuratK. : i would want the `copy` to happen within `util`, so kind of avoiding this approach!!

Comment: You don't need this class at the current state. Simply provide a copy constructor and call `new Human(human)`.

Comment: Actual issue is that `Human` / `Car` etc are codebases which are not in my control and they do not have this functionality of `copy` `const`, hence all this mess. Thats why i want to contain this within `Util` :|

Comment: You should get a library that will do the cloning for you, that way you don't have to waste time writing (bad) code. They're fully generic too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to get this done with Generics (using )? or is this
>   a bad approach in the first place to do?

It is a bad approach because you receive as parameter a `Object`.
You cannot infer from that the concrete type : whereas the `instanceof` you used.    Which is not a fine approach.
Here two ideas (related enough)

**1) Introducing a Copyable interface**

You could introduce an interface that the classes of the objects you want to copy implement :

```
public interface Copyable<T> {
    T copy(T t);
}
```

that could be implemented such as :

```
public class Human implements Copyable<Human> {

   @Override
   public Human copy(Human t) {
       return    Human.builder()
                     .name(human.getName())
                     .age(human.getAge())
                     .build();
   }

}
```

So the general copy() method could look like :

```
// the main wrapper
static <T extends Copyable<T>> T copyObject(T payload) {
    return payload.copy(payload);
}
```

And you could use it in this way :

```
Human human = new Human();
// set some fields  ...
Human copiedHuman = copyObject(human); // compile
Car copiedCar = copyObject(human); // doesn't compile
```

**2) Use the visitor pattern**

As alternative, it is also a good case for the visitor pattern : you want to apply a processing according to the concrete type of the parameter.
It allows to group together copy operations as in your actual code.

The general `copyObject()` method could rely on `CopyVisitor` that will do the copy according to the concrete type of the parameter :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T extends Visited> T copyObject(T payload) {
    CopyVisitor visitor = new CopyVisitor();
    payload.accept(visitor);
    return (T) visitor.getCopy();
}
```

Where `CopyVisitor` implements a classic `Visitor` interface :

```
public interface Visitor {  
    void visitHuman(Human human);
    void visitCar(Car car);
    void visitPlanet(Planet planet);
}
```

in this way :

```
public class CopyVisitor implements Visitor {

    private Visited copy;

    @Override
    public void visitHuman(Human human) {
        copy = Human.builder()
                    .name(human.getName())
                    .age(human.getAge())
                    .build();

    }

    @Override
    public void visitCar(Car car) {
        copy = Car.builder()
                  .model(car.getModel())
                  .brand(car.getBrand())
                  .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void visitPlanet(Planet planet) {
        //...
    }

    public Visited getCopy() {
        return copy;
    }

}
```

The visited classes (Car, Human, Plan) would implement a specific interface to "accept" the visitor :

```
public interface Visited {
    void accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

such as :

```
public class Human implements Visited {

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitHuman(this);
    }

}
```

So you can use the `copy()` method in this way :

```
Human human = new Human();
// set some fields  ...
Human copiedHuman = copyObject(human); // compile
Car copiedCar = copyObject(human); // doesn't compile
```

Comment: there's no need for `Copyable`, there is `UnaryOperator`

Comment: This is right but `public class Human implements Copyable<Human>{...}`  is more meaningful than `public class Human implements UnaryOperator<Human> {...}`

Comment: just thinking how much I don't like/understand visitor pattern, this is awesome! plus one!

Comment: @Eugene Ah ok. But well I also prefer `human.copy(human)` to human.apply(human)` for the same reasons : more readable :) Thanks :) I am not a fan either of the visitor pattern but in some cases it may be not so bad :)

Comment: Very nice answer. But I feel storing the result of the copy in an instance variable `copy` and then calling `getCopy()` seems weird... Any thoughts?

Comment: @user7 Very good point. It is the drawback to use the visitor pattern when we want the visitor to return something. We could modify both the visited and the visitor classes  by adding a common return type . But it doesn't allow any longer to generalize the visitor pattern if we have visitors classes that don't require any return. Now in cases where we need to return the same type instance in multiple visitors subclass, doing this change makes sense. It is often how pattern work. Half baked and we have to finish it according to our requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to do some unchecked casts like this:

```
static <TPayload> TPayload copyObject(Object payload) {
    if (payload instanceof Human)
        return (TPayload) copyEntry((Human) payload);
    if (payload instanceof Car)
        return (TPayload) copyEntry((Car) payload);
    if (payload instanceof Planet)
        return (TPayload) copyEntry((Planet) payload);
    return (TPayload) payload;
}
```

But as mentioned in the comments this does not prevent you from writing:

```
Number n = DataUtil.copyObject("someString");
```

Comment: The compile-time type of a variable can be broader than the actual instance, just like with `Object o = "foo";`, so this has nothing to do with type erasure, you would need the `instanceof` checks anyway, if you want to react on the actual object type rather than the compile-time declaration. Besides that, your generic signature promises to return whatever the caller wishes, regardless of what they passed in, which is, of course, fundamentally broken. E.g., it allows to write `Number n = copyObject("someString");`…

Comment: @Holger right. Removed type erasure from the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge about the type in Object you can do it with:

```
static <T> T copyObject(Object payload)
    {
        if (payload instanceof Human)
        {
            return (T) copyEntry((Human) payload);
        }
        if (payload instanceof Car)
        {
            return (T) copyEntry((Car) payload);
        }
        if (payload instanceof Planet)
        {
            return (T) copyEntry((Planet) payload);
        }
        return (T) payload;
    };
```

and then:

```
Human h1 = new ...
Human h2= copyObject(h1);
```

Even if Java's Type Erasure would not apply you need runtime knowledge for your language to do so aka "dependent typing".

So return type overloading found in some languages like in C++ wouldn't help for runtime type switches like in `List<Object>`.

But why you need this anyway, you will collect all object instances after the call in a new heterogeneous List again